# Alternative to timegm on Solaris

Tags: c++, solaris, solaris-10

I have a program that was originally written for Linux, but I now have a requirement to get it running on Solaris 10.

Part of this program uses the [timegm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timegm.3.html) function to convert a `struct tm` into a `time_t` epoch seconds value. The input time is referenced to UTC.

Trying to compile this program on Solaris, it fails because `timegm` cannot be found. After some googling I realized that this function has been removed from Solaris a long time ago (and even the Linux manpage recommends against using it, because it isn't standardized).

However I have so far not been able to find an alternative function, that takes a `struct tm` referenced to UTC and converts to epoch time. Most references I found on the net recommend using [mktime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktime.html), however that function interprets the inputs with reference to the system local time zone.

Note that I do not wish to use `tzset` to force the timezone to UTC, as that would have other side effects on the program.

So my question is: how can I convert a `struct tm` broken down time value, expressed with respect to UTC, into an epoch time, in the absence of `timegm`?

The program is written in C++ so I'm not limited to C solutions, although I would prefer not to embark on a wholesale rewrite to use some additional time library.

Comment: If it is not to late: I've just uploaded a standalone implementation: https://github.com/lzsiga/timegm (public domain licence).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `days_from_civil` which is [described here in detail](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#days_from_civil)

```
// Returns number of days since civil 1970-01-01.  Negative values indicate
//    days prior to 1970-01-01.
// Preconditions:  y-m-d represents a date in the civil (Gregorian) calendar
//                 m is in [1, 12]
//                 d is in [1, last_day_of_month(y, m)]
//                 y is "approximately" in
//                   [numeric_limits<Int>::min()/366, numeric_limits<Int>::max()/366]
//                 Exact range of validity is:
//                 [civil_from_days(numeric_limits<Int>::min()),
//                  civil_from_days(numeric_limits<Int>::max()-719468)]
template <class Int>
constexpr
Int
days_from_civil(Int y, unsigned m, unsigned d) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits >= 18,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit unsigned integer");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<Int>::digits >= 20,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit signed integer");
    y -= m <= 2;
    const Int era = (y >= 0 ? y : y-399) / 400;
    const unsigned yoe = static_cast<unsigned>(y - era * 400);      // [0, 399]
    const unsigned doy = (153*(m + (m > 2 ? -3 : 9)) + 2)/5 + d-1;  // [0, 365]
    const unsigned doe = yoe * 365 + yoe/4 - yoe/100 + doy;         // [0, 146096]
    return era * 146097 + static_cast<Int>(doe) - 719468;
}
```

to convert the {year, month, day} triple in the `tm` to a count of days since the epoch (1970-01-01).  Be careful when converting these fields from `tm` for their eccentricities (e.g. `tm_year + 1900`).

Multiply this count of days by 86400 and add to that the {hours, minutes, seconds} data from the `tm` (each converted to seconds).

And you're done.  Don't worry about leap seconds, `timegm` didn't worry about them either.  If you're really concerned about leap seconds I have a [C++11/14 solution available to deal with that](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#utc_clock), but I'm guessing that is more than you want to get into.

Don't be put off by the C++14 syntax shown above.  It is trivial to convert this algorithm to C (or any other language for that matter).

Comment: NIce one. That date algorithms page of yours is a fantastic resource

Answer (score 0):

Per [the POSIX standard for `tzset()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tzset.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <time.h>
>
> extern int daylight;
> extern long timezone;
>
> extern char *tzname[2];
> void tzset(void);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The `tzset()` function also shall set the external variable daylight
>   to 0 if Daylight Savings Time conversions should never be applied for
>   the timezone in use; otherwise, non-zero. **The external variable
>   `timezone` shall be set to the difference, in seconds, between
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) and local standard time.**

You should be able to call `tzset()` to set the value in `timezone`, then use `mktime()` to get the time in the current timezone, then apply the difference in the `timezone` variable to to the result from `mktime()` to convert that result to UTC.

I don't have access to Solaris right now to test that.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of that, but the difference between UTC and local time isn't constant, it depends on the time being converted. For example if I convert '2016-12-01 10:00' in my timezone to UTC the difference would be different to '2016-06-01 10:00' because of daylight savings.